# DSCP to p bit mapping in Linux

Tags: dscp

Re posting from Unix forum as it may be appropriate for networking forum
I have the following setup

```
Linux1--------------------------------------------Linux2
eth0 10.10.10.30                                  eth0 10.10.10.10
eth0.50 20.20.20.30                               eth0.50 20.20.20.20
```

I want to enable DSCP to p bit mapping for all packets going out from Linux1 to Linux2

The ping i used on Linux1 is from busybox ( doesnt have -Q option).I have to use iptables to set dscp

When i use the command

```
# iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p icmp -j DSCP --set-dscp 49
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Do not know what could be wrong. I read online that i have to set DSCP and SKB priority and then map skb priority to pbits, I also use the command

```
vconfig set_egress_map eth0.50 49 3
```

This always sets the PRI bit to 3. But i do not see the DSCP value set in the outgoing packets IP header.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but this is off-topic on NE. This would be better suited for superuser.